# UIButton being affected by gestures

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView that responds to gestures and would like to have a UIButton in this view that responds to a touch up inside. at the moment the gestures beneath the UIButton seem to be interfering with the touch up inside.

any advice would be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to solve your problem.

[See this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10170/discussion-between-aalok-parikh-and-marvin)